# How to generate a matrix whose indicate from 0 to 3

Tags: matrices, maple

When I use:

> Matrix(4, symbol = g, shape = symmetric)

I get a matrix of g_{1,1} to g_{4,4}.

However what I want is g_{0,0} to g_{3,3}.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
> f := (i, j)->g(i-1, j-1);
> Matrix(4, symbol = g, shape = symmetric, f);
```

But this gives a function for $g$, I don't know how to set a symbol instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a Matrix `G` whose entries range from `g[0,0]` (which pretty-prints subscripted) to `g[3,3]`.

```
G:=Matrix(4, (i,j)->g[i-1,j-1], shape = symmetric)

# Indexing into a Matrix starts at 1.
#
G[1,1], G[4,4];

# Assignments are made respecting the symmetry.
#
G[2,3] := W;
G[3,2];

G;
```

The above Matrix `G` has the `symmetric` indexing function. But its entries are accessed starting at 1, since its a Matrix.

In Maple you can also create an `Array` (rather than a `Matrix`) whose indexing can start at whatever you choose when you create it. So you could have its indexing start from 0, say.

However, the stock `symmetric` indexing function is not available for an Array whose indexing does not start at 1. But we can construct our own indexing-function (which does just what we'd expect from a symmetric indexing function) for such Arrays.

```
# indexing function for symmetric A whose entries don't need to start from 1.
# You only need to create this once per session (or LibraryTools:-Save it for re-use).
#
`index/ssymmetric` := proc(idx::list(nonnegint), P::Array, val::list)
   local idx1, init_val;
   if nops(idx) <> 2 then
     error "ssymmetric custom indexing requires exactly 2 indices";
   end if;
   if nargs = 2 then
     if idx[2]>idx[1] then
       P[idx[1],idx[2]];
     else
       P[idx[2],idx[1]];
     end if;
   else
     try
       if idx[2]>idx[1] then
         P[idx[1],idx[2]] := op(val);
       else
         P[idx[2],idx[1]] := op(val);
       end if;
     catch "unable to store":
       op( val );
     end try;
  end if;
end proc:


B:=Array(ssymmetric,0..3,0..3, (i,j)->`if`(j>i,g[i,j],g[j,i])):

# This Array's indexing starts at 0.
#
B[0,0], B[2,3], B[3,2];

B[1,2] := W;
B[2,1];

# To print it nicely, we can wrap it in a `Matrix` call.
Matrix(B);
```